# Mapping list of fields of a type to array type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type like

```
type MyType = {
  x: number
  y: string
}
```

I'd like a type (say `Mapper`) that converts a list of fields into a type as follows

```
type TypeOfArray = Mapper<['x', 'y']>
```

so that constructing `TypeOfArray` in this way has the same effect as

```
type TypeOfArray = [number, string]
```

Is this possible in Typescript 3.5?  I've been playing around with mapped tuples but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I'd probably write it like this:

```
type GenericMapper<T, KS> = {
  [K in keyof KS]: KS[K] extends keyof T ? T[KS[K]] : never
};
```

This takes a type `T` and an object/array of keys `KS`, and makes a new object/array the same shape as `KS` but with the values replaced with the corresponding property from `T` (or `never` if there is no corresponding property).  It's [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `KS`, which also [works for tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) since TS3.1.

The important bit is probably the nested [property lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), `T[KS[K]]`.  For each key `K` of `KS`, we're taking the `KS[K]` property, which we expect to be some key of `T`, (which will be `MyType` in your case), and looking it up in `T` to get `T[KS[K]]`.  If `T` is `MyType`, and `KS` is `["x","y"]`, and `K` is `"0"`, then `KS[K]` is `"x"`, and `T[KS[K]]` is `T["x"]` is `number`.

Then your `Mapper` is something like

```
type MyType = {
  x: number
  y: string
}

type Mapper<KS> = GenericMapper<MyType, KS>;
```

And you can see it works as you expect:

```
type TypeOfArray = Mapper<['x', 'y']>
//type TypeOfArray = [number, string]
```

Not sure if this meets all your use cases, but it should hopefully give you an idea how to proceed.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgWQIZkkgPACoA0UA0gMoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANplQrxQDWEEAHsAZuQoBdAFwSukqBAAewBABMAzgKFiohKAH49XCvIWzEAN2SsAvgG5WTlqEhQMIQuGj1mbKEoWAK4AtgBGNv4gshrAqPAA5nbOrtDYuMj4lDT0cIiomDh4+B5ekKTZjiysqXreAPKiAIJISFggdO5FmRwA5Eq9pL0gvZJUrAD0E7VlEI0tbR30HPChEUiksfEJkkA)

Comment: Nice one! If you add `KS extends (keyof T)[]` then it will also only allow you to pick properties that actually exist on `T`, so that `Mapper<['a']>` is an error instead of `[never]`.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the use case, I guess.

Comment: this looks great!  I see I was missing two ingredients in my attempts: the nested lookup and the conditional. thanks!